# mysql result to reorganaize the result

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

```
SELECT app, result, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM table
GROUP BY app, result
```

return me next:

```
app|result|cnt|
ap1|FAIL  |111|
ap1|PASS  |99 |
ap2|FAIL  |222|
ap3|PASS  |333|
```

**but I need this way:**

```
app|cnt_FAIL|cnt_PASS|

ap1|111     |99      |  
ap2|222     |0       |
ap3|0       |333     |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
SELECT app, 
       SUM (case when result = 'PASS' then 1 else 0 end ) cnt_pass,
       SUM (case when result = 'FAIL' then 1 else 0 end ) cnt_fail
FROM table
GROUP BY app
```

Comment: FUNCTION dbname.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual